# How to set the username/password on Websphere MQ connection string from .Net / C#?

Tags: authentication, connection-string, ibm-mq, mq

How to I specify the username and password in a wmq connection string? This is the sample connection string I'm working with.

```
        Uri sampleAddress = new Uri("wmq://localhost:1414/msg/queue/Q1?connectQueueManager=QM1&replyTo=Q2");
```

How do I put the userId/password used for authentication to the MQ Manager here?

Comment: What version of MQ client are you using? Also what client are you using? MQ .NET or XMS ,NET or MQ WCF?

Comment: MQ client version is 8, the server I'm trying to connect to is 7.5. The client I'm using is MQ WCF.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

For V8.0 I was successful by making the connection in the following way:

```
Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();                             
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _queueServer);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _portNumber);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _channelInfo);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "userid");
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");                    
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManager, connectionProperties);
```

See [here](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=60671&sid=608a15d83d138cb1260554156f3e9f6c).
Although for version below 8.0 please see that you will have to use an exit mechanism as for them the client provided id is not used.

Comment: @PavelBiryukov which property are you referring to?

Comment: MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY
Did you have a look at WCF samples?

Comment: MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY is part of the MQ.NET libraries.

Comment: Sure :) Please have a look at wcf samples:
The path is
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\wcf\samples\WCF

There is no direct creation of MQQueueManager